# How to specify uniqueness for a tuple of field in a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to specify a Model in Django such that is ensures that pair of fields in unique in the table, in a way similar to the "unique=True" attribute for similar field?

Or do I need to check this constraint in the clean() method?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a META option called `unique_together`. For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.BlahField()
    field2 = models.FooField()
    field3 = models.BazField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("field1", "field2")
```

More info on the Django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) page.

Comment: META should not be in all caps; it should be "class Meta:"